# Android: How to detect these objects in images? (Image included). Tried OpenCV and metaioSDK, but both are not working good enough

Tags: android, object-detection

i have been working with object detection / recognition in images captured from an android device camera recently.

the object i am trying to detect are all kinds of buttons that look like this:

[Picture of buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Fl52.jpg)

so far i have been trying with OpenCV and also with the metaio SDK. **results:**

**OpenCV** was always detecting something, but gave lots of false hits. also it is too much work to collect all the pictures for what i have in mind. i have tried three ways with OpenCV:

1. **FeatureDetection** (SURF, ORB and so on) -> was way too slow and not enough features on my objects.
2. **Template Matching** -> seems to only work when the template is exactly a part out of the scene image
3. **Training classifiers** -> this worked the best so far, but is too much work for my goal, and still gives too many false detections.

**metaioSDK** was working ok when i took my reference images (the icon part of each button) out of a picture like shown above, then printed the full image and pointed my android device camera at the printed picture. but when i tried with the real buttons (not a picture of them) then almost nothing got detected anymore. in the metaio documentation it is said that the reference images need to have lots of features and color differences and also should not only consist of white text. well, as you see my reference images are exactly the opposite from what they should be. but thats just how the buttons look ;)

**so, my question would be:** does any of you have a suggestion about what else i could try to detect and recognize each of those buttons when i point my android camera at them?

Comment: Can you say in more details what have you tried to do in OpenCV?

Comment: @IvanAslamov thanks for your reply, i have updated my question with that information.

Comment: @user2677466 i want to do this, can you give me link of source code, so i can do it smoothly, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion can you try the following approach:
[Class-Specific Hough Forest for Object Detection](http://www.vision.ee.ethz.ch/~gallju/projects/houghforest/)
they provide a C code implementation. Compile and run it and see the results, then replace positive and negative training images with the ones you have according the following rules:

In a car you will need to define the following 3 areas:

1. target region (the image you provided is a good representation of a target region)
2. nearby working area (this area have information regarding you target relative location) I would recommend: area 3-5 times the target regions, around the target, can be a good working area
3. everything outside the above can be used as negative images

then,

1. Use "many" positive images (100-1000) at different viewing angles (-30 - +30 degrees) and various distances.

You will have to make assumptions at which viewing angles and distances your users will use the application. The more strict they are the better performance you will get. A simple "hint" camera overlay can give a good idea to people what you expect the working area to be.

1. Use few times (3-5) more different negative image set which includes pictures of things that might be in the camera but should not contribute any target position information.
2. Do not use big images, somewhere around 100-300px in width should be enough

Assemble the database, and modify the configuration file that the code comes with. Run the program, see if performance is OK for your needs.

The program will return a voting map cloud of the object you are looking fore. Add gaussian blur to it, and apply some threshold to it (you will have to make another assumption for this threshold value).

Extracted mask will define the area you are looking for. The size of the masked region can give you good estimate of the object scale. Given this information it will be much easier to select proper template and perform template matching.

(Also some thoughts) You can also try to do a small trick by using goodFeaturesToTrack function with the mask you got, to get a set of locations and compare them with the corresponding locations on a template. Constuct an SSD and solve it for rotation, scale and transition parameters, by mimizing alignment error (but not sure if this approach will work)